# Why is the Fourier transformation full of spikes with 12.5 Hz frequency steps?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform

I am performing a fourier transformation in matlab for time signal data with monitoring points for pressure extracted from a simulation.

What I get at the end is a spectrum as shown below:
[image]

I am wondering why the spectrum consists of MANY spikes which have all a distance of 12.5 Hz. The data is measured with 15.152 kHz for a period of T=1.2 s.

I am using the following code to perform the fourier transformation for [this data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aUh3I3oV6AwStC7Gq46wtZb1B2DDOhVs/view?usp=sharing):

```
data= readmatrix('MP_Pressure_Combined_1st+3rdDataSet_timmed_superuser.xlsx');



for i=1:2
t = data(:,1);
x = data(:,i+2)-mean(data(:,i+2));
TimeSignalSize = size(data(:,i+2),1);

fig1=figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(t,x)
xlabel('t (s)') 
ylabel('Absolute Pressure Pa') 
tit=['Monitoring Point Nr.' num2str(i)];
title(tit)
ts=t(2,1)- t(1,1);
T=t(TimeSignalSize,1)-t(1,1);
Fs=1/ts;
N = Fs*(T);
f=0:1/T:Fs;
X = fft(x);

subplot(1,2,2)
plot(f,2*abs(X)/TimeSignalSize)
tit=['Monitoring Point Nr.' num2str(i)];
title(tit)
xlim([0 1000])
xlabel('f (Hz)') 
ylabel('Amplitude') 
saveas(fig1,['Monitoring Point Nr.' num2str(i) '.png'])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have freequency components in a regular raster, we call these *harmonics*. A perfect harmonic oscillation has only one frequency component, but everything that is periodic, but not perfectly sine-shaped will have frequency components at multiples of its *fundamental frequency*.

That fundamental frequency seems to be 12.5 Hz in your case. So, look for things that are periodic, but not sinusoidal in your signal, with period 1/12.5 s = 1/80 s.

---

Also, quick note: you're using excel files to store simulated data. That's classically a bad idea – Excel uses its very own version of directed rounding for numerical values, which is a nonlinear distortion and will, for example, give a perfect sine (which doesn't have any harmonics) harmonics. (But they will be nowhere as large as your harmonics here, so that has nothing to do with the question you're having). Such numerical errors in storage can lead to what is called "chaotic behaviour" when used for further computations; the [wikipedia article on Chaos Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#History) has a nice paragraph on how Lorenz found that out the hard way, when he used an imperfect-precision printout of his simulated data instead of the actual internal data to continue a simulation.

Your simulator should not be generating excel files; that's just not a very good data exchange format. Most CSV is bad, for reasons of size and numerical accuracy itself. If possible, use the HDF5 output format that matlab can directly read – but I really don't know your simulator software; it's possible Excel export is the best option you have.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes you are right, in the left figure, if one calculates time diffference from peak to peak the period will be 0.08 s or 12.5 Hz. 
Is there anyway to solve this issue and to obtain a smooth spectrum?

Comment: It's not an issue. It's how your spectrum is! There's nothing wrong with this, inherently. Why do you think it's a problem?